# What will be the time complexity of the following code? O(nlogn) or O(N)? When is the complexity O(nlogn)?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am a little confused while calculating the time complexity of this code. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
N=4
index=1
sum=0
while index < N:
    j = N
    while j >= index:
        j =j//4
        sum+=10
    index+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity is O().

We see that:

When index > /4, then there is only 1 inner iteration: this happens in the majority of the outer iterations: in about (3/4) of the outer iterations.

Else, when index > /16, there are 2 inner iterations.

...etc.

We can write this as the following sum:

(3/4) + 2(3/4²) + 3(3/4³) + ...

And we can extract the 3 coefficient:

3[ 1/4 + 2/4² + 3/4³ + ... ]

What remains is a power series in a form that is listed on [Wikipedia - low order polylogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Low-order_polylogarithms):

∑<sub><sub>k=1..∞</sub></sub>  =  / (1 − )²

...where  = 1/4, and so that series converges towards a constant value. In reality we have a finite number of terms in this series, but this infinite one already gives us a constant upper bound.

That leaves us with 3 which is obviously linear in .

Therefore the complexity is O()

### Illustration

To illustrate this complexity, watch how the following script outputs the ratio between   and the number of times the inner loop's body executes in total... it converges towards a constant:

```js
function test(n) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let index = 1; index < n; index++) {
        for (let j = n; j >= index; j >>= 2) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

for (let n = 1; n < 1e7; n*=2) {
    console.log(test(n) / n);
}
```

This is of course not a proof, but an illustration of what was concluded above.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start by analysing the inner loop. Since `j = j//4` in one iteration, and `j` goes from `N` to `<=index`, the inner loop will take `ceil(log((N+1)/index))` time for a given index.
2. `index` goes from `1` to `N`.
3. Using 1 & 2, total `time = ceil(log(N/1)) + ceil(log(N/2)) + ceil(log(N/3)) ... ceil(log(N/N))`.
4. Let's pick a random value for index in `N/index`. When `index` is in range `[1, N/4)`, we get `ceil(log(N/index)) = 1`. When `index` is in range `[N/4, N/16)`, we get `ceil(log(N/index)) = 2`.
5. To generalize, when index is in range `[N/4^x, N/4^(x-1))`, the value of `ceil(log(N/index)) = x`. The count of numbers in this range is `N/4^(x-1) - N/4^x = 3N/(4^x)`.
6. `x` goes from `1` to `log(N)`, so our summation becomes sum of `3N * (x/4^x)` over all `x`. Since `3N` is constant, we need to find summation of `x/4^x` over all `x`.
7. As pointed out by @trincot, the summation has a constant upper bound. So we get `O(3N * constant)` = `O(3N)` = `O(N)`.

So the overall time complexity is `O(N)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Mathur. It's very helpful.

Comment: @trincot I have fixed the premise and summation, but do you know the actual bound for it?

Comment: I have posted an answer. The complexity is not O(NlogN).